# Please Help: PHP Fatal error: looks like we got no XML document

Tags: php, xml, soap, soapfault

I'm getting crazy with this error I've tried all issues in forums nothing works I'm getting disappointed. Help Please with this

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document

Please guys,I would really appreciate the help

Comment: you are not passing any xml data in your soap request

Comment: The clue, as usual, is in the error message. Guess you got no valid xml document as input. Try validating your xml and make sure you do actually have a document you are using as input

Comment: I guess you need to give a lot more information before people can help you, where are you having this error? show some code, etc ...

Comment: I've a wsdl file and it's valid

Comment: I check getLastRequest()=>NULL and getLastResponse()=>NULL

Comment: Please guys,I would really appreciate the help

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs when the response from the soap server cannot be parsed as XML.

Reasons for this:

1. The HTTP body of the response has the wrong `Content-Type`.
2. The content is no XML at all, because the PHP script triggered a fatal error, or an uncatched exception, or simply `die()`d.
3. The content contains PHP error output like notices, warnings etc.

How to see what it is?

Use a different soap client, like [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/). This one will display what you got as response, even if it isn't parsable XML.